# Adding new project to the solution

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, solution

I am creating currently a WCF application in MS Visual Studio 2010 for demonstrative reasons. I follow the instructions from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx). In the 4th step :” [Create a Windows Communication Foundation Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx)” I have problem to execute the instruction 1a:

“In Solution Explorer (on the upper right) within the same solution that contains the service, right-click the current solution (not the project), and select Add, and then New Project.”

In particular, I cannot find the Solution which I must click. In the Solution explorer exists the only project and by right click there is no opportunity to add a project but only an item. Where is the Solution from where I can add the new project? Should I have take are of it at the time of project creation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select Tools-> Options, Select Projects and solutions out of that, there is one option "Always show solution". See the picture

[image: Showing solution]

Answer (score 2):

You can either add the project from the *File* menu, as others have suggested, but the reason you cannot see the solution if because of a setting in Visual Studio, which you can change in *Tools* > *Options*:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can find the option to display the Solution in
Tools > Projects and Solutions > General > **Always show solution**

What this does is (quoted from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8919d7f2%28VS.80%29.aspx)):

> **Always show solution**
>
> When selected, the solution and all commands that
> act on solutions are always shown in the IDE. When cleared, all
> projects are created as stand-alone projects and you do not see the
> solution in Solution Explorer or commands that act on solutions in the
> IDE if the solution contains only one project.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the main menu:

```
File --> Add --> New Project
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add it by File > New > Project (CTRL+SHIFT+N)

Answer (score 0):

You should create your project within a solution.  How did you create your project?  Anyway, VS ususally offers to save your project within a solution after the first build.  So, try to build your project.